# Apache Cordova App not receiving XMLHttpRequest responseText

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

The app works fine in the Ripple Emulator (an in-browser Android Emulator), but doesn't work when run on an actual device. On the device I can tell the request runs fine because the body's HTML does change to "RESULT: ". However the responseText is an empty string. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "Hello, World";
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var xhr;    
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://testinggrounds.5gbfree.com/ss/a.php", true);


xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "RESULT: " + xhr.responseText;
    }
}
xhr.send();
```